Four-language parallel text across facing pages in XeLaTeX
I'm trying to create a book with parallel text in four languages (English, German, French, Italian) using XeLaTeX. My goal is to have two languages on each facing page:

Left (even) page: English and German
Right (odd) page: French and Italian

This answer is not satisfactory, as the MWE provided there does not produce text on two opposite pages, but just on four columns instead.
I'm using the paracol package, but I can't figure out how to split the columns across two pages. Currently, all four languages appear on the same page, which doesn't work well with my A6 paper size. Below the current result. Four languages on four columns, all on the same page. Way too cluttered.

Here's a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue. Compile with XeLaTeX.
\documentclass[a6paper,10pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{italian}

% Language commands
\newcommand{\en}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}
\newcommand{\de}[1]{\textgerman{#1}}
\newcommand{\fr}[1]{\textfrench{#1}}
\newcommand{\ital}[1]{\textitalian{#1}}

% Character commands
\newcommand{\lord}[1]{\textit{Lord:} #1}
\newcommand{\servant}[1]{\textit{Servant:} #1}
\newcommand{\people}[1]{\textit{People:} #1}


% ====== Document Start ======
\begin{document}

\ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi  % Ensure it's an even page (left)

\begin{paracol}{4}

\en{\lord{Jeeves! Where's my morning tea?}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Jeeves! Wo ist mein Morgentee?}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Jeeves ! Où est mon thé du matin ?}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Jeeves! Dov'è il mio tè del mattino?}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\servant{Coming, sir. I was polishing the silver.}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\servant{Kommt sofort, Sir. Ich habe das Silber poliert.}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\servant{J'arrive, monsieur. Je polissais l'argenterie.}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\servant{Arrivo, signore. Stavo lucidando l'argenteria.}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Bother the silver! Tea first, man!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Zum Teufel mit dem Silber! Zuerst der Tee, Mann!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Au diable l'argenterie ! Le thé d'abord, voyons !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Al diavolo l'argenteria! Prima il tè, uomo!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\people{Good morning, Lord Fancypants!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\people{Guten Morgen, Lord Schickehose!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\people{Bonjour, Lord Culottes-Chics !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\people{Buongiorno, Lord Pantaloni-Eleganti!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Good heavens! Peasants on my lawn?}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Gütiger Himmel! Bauern auf meinem Rasen?}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Bon sang ! Des paysans sur ma pelouse ?}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Cielo santo! Contadini sul mio prato?}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\servant{It seems they've organized a festival, sir.}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\servant{Es scheint, sie haben ein Fest organisiert, Sir.}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\servant{Il semble qu'ils aient organisé une fête, monsieur.}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\servant{Sembra che abbiano organizzato una festa, signore.}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{A festival? Preposterous! My riding crop, Jeeves!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Ein Fest? Lächerlich! Meine Reitgerte, Jeeves!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Une fête ? Absurde ! Ma cravache, Jeeves !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Una festa? Assurdo! Il mio frustino, Jeeves!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\people{We've brought pies and ale, m'lord!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\people{Wir haben Kuchen und Bier mitgebracht, Mylord!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\people{Nous avons apporté des tartes et de la bière, monseigneur !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\people{Abbiamo portato torte e birra, mio signore!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Pies and ale? How frightfully common.}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Kuchen und Bier? Wie schrecklich gewöhnlich.}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Des tartes et de la bière ? Quelle vulgarité.}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Torte e birra? Che volgarità.}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\servant{Shall I prepare cucumber sandwiches instead, sir?}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\servant{Soll ich stattdessen Gurkensandwiches zubereiten, Sir?}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\servant{Dois-je préparer des sandwichs au concombre à la place, monsieur ?}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\servant{Devo preparare sandwich al cetriolo invece, signore?}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Oh, very well. Let's join this rustic gathering.}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Na schön. Lasst uns an diesem rustikalen Treffen teilnehmen.}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Eh bien, soit. Joignons-nous à ce rassemblement rustique.}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Ebbene, va bene. Uniamoci a questo raduno rustico.}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\people{We've set up a maypole for dancing!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\people{Wir haben einen Maibaum zum Tanzen aufgestellt!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\people{Nous avons installé un mât de mai pour danser !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\people{Abbiamo allestito un palo della cuccagna per ballare!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Dancing? In my wellington boots? How avant-garde!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Tanzen? In meinen Gummistiefeln? Wie avantgardistisch!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Danser ? Dans mes bottes en caoutchouc ? Quelle avant-garde !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Ballare? Con i miei stivali di gomma? Che avanguardia!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\people{Look at Lord Fancypants go!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\people{Seht euch Lord Schickehose an!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\people{Regardez Lord Culottes-Chics y aller !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\people{Guardate Lord Pantaloni-Eleganti come si dà da fare!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{I say, this is rather invigorating!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Ich muss sagen, das ist ziemlich belebend!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Je dois dire que c'est plutôt vivifiant !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Devo dire che è piuttosto rinvigorente!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\servant{Shall we retire for the evening, sir?}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\servant{Sollen wir uns für den Abend zurückziehen, Sir?}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\servant{Devrions-nous nous retirer pour la soirée, monsieur ?}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\servant{Dovremmo ritirarci per la serata, signore?}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Nonsense! The night is young, Jeeves!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Unsinn! Die Nacht ist jung, Jeeves!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Sottises ! La nuit est jeune, Jeeves !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Sciocchezze! La notte è giovane, Jeeves!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\people{His Lordship is attempting a jig!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\people{Seine Lordschaft versucht einen Jig!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\people{Sa Seigneurie essaie de danser une gigue !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\people{Sua Signoria sta tentando una giga!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Jeeves, add 'Irish dancing' to my accomplishments!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{Jeeves, fügen Sie 'Irischer Tanz' zu meinen Errungenschaften hinzu!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Jeeves, ajoutez 'danse irlandaise' à mes réalisations !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Jeeves, aggiungi 'danza irlandese' ai miei successi!}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\servant{And 'falling with style', sir?}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\servant{Und 'Stilvoll Fallen', Sir?}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\servant{Et 'chuter avec style', monsieur ?}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\servant{E 'cadere con stile', signore?}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\lord{Was that sarcasm, Jeeves?}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\lord{War das Sarkasmus, Jeeves?}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\lord{Était-ce du sarcasme, Jeeves ?}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\lord{Era sarcasmo quello, Jeeves?}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\servant{Merely an observation on your unique style, sir.}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\servant{Nur eine Beobachtung Ihres einzigartigen Stils, Sir.}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\servant{Simplement une observation sur votre style unique, monsieur.}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\servant{Solo un'osservazione sul suo stile unico, signore.}}

\switchcolumn*
\en{\people{Another round for Lord Fancypants!}}
\switchcolumn
\de{\people{Noch eine Runde für Lord Schickehose!}}
\switchcolumn
\fr{\people{Une autre tournée pour Lord Culottes-Chics !}}
\switchcolumn
\ital{\people{Un altro giro per Lord Pantaloni-Eleganti!}}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}

This produces four columns on a single page, but I need:

English and German on the left (even) page
French and Italian on the right (odd) page

I've tried various approaches, including using \cleardoublepage and multiple paracol environments, but I can't get it to work consistently for a long text.
Additionally, there are some text wrapping issues where text overflows into adjacent columns. While fixing this would be helpful, my primary concern is getting the four-language layout to work across facing pages.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this layout would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

\begin{paracol}[2]{4} four columns, two on the left page.  See page 12.

@JohnKormylo , oh really, was it that simple...? Wow!!! "See page 12", do you mean page 12 of the "parallel" documentation, i.e. doing texdoc paracolfrom a terminal? May I ask you how I should have proceeded in finding an answer? The paracol documentation is quite long, and reading everything for "just" this solution would have not proved efficient...

@JohnKormylo, true, I mistyped parallel instead of paracol. Thanks anyway, neat solutions are always easy!

Also, I believe paracol changed its manual recently.  You might want to update you packages.

Reading the documentation may seem tedious and tiring at times, but you could search within the PDF for reasonable keywords. More often than not it is still the best way to find a nice solution =)

@JasperHabicht totally. I completed forgot the documentation and I was trying intertwined methods suggested from LLM models... Which apparently do not know the pdf of the paracol package! Thanks a lot for your input, will refer to the documentation from now on!
